# Kendo PanelBar in Kendo Scheduler EditTemplate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a Scheduler:

```
      @(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<HTServices.Models.TaskViewModel>()
            .Name("scheduler")
            .Date(DateTime.Now)
            .StartTime(new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 7, 00, 00))
            .Height(600)
            .Editable(edit =>
            {
                edit.TemplateName("ScheduleItemTemplate");
                edit.Create(false);
                edit.Destroy(false);
            })
            .Views(views =>
            {
                views.DayView();
                views.WeekView(workWeekView => workWeekView.Selected(true));
                views.MonthView();
                views.AgendaView();
            })
            .DataSource(d => d
                .Model(m =>
                {
                    m.Id(f => f.TaskID);
                    m.Field(f => f.Title).DefaultValue("No title");
                    m.Field(f => f.OwnerID).DefaultValue(1);
                    m.Field(f => f.Title).DefaultValue("No title");
                    m.RecurrenceId(f => f.RecurrenceID);
                })
                .Read("Read", "Scheduler")
                .Create("Create", "Scheduler")
                .Destroy("Destroy", "Scheduler")
                .Update("Update", "Scheduler")
            )
        )
```

It loads great with my custom template.

```
@model HTServices.Models.TaskViewModel
@{
    //required in order to render validation attributes
    ViewContext.FormContext = new FormContext();
}

@functions{


}

<div class="k-edit-label">
    @(Html.LabelFor(model => model.Client))
</div>
<div data-container-for="client" class="k-edit-field">
    @(Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Client, new { style = "width:100%;", @readonly = "readonly", @class = "k-textbox col-lg-12", data_bind = "text: client" }))
</div>
<div class="k-edit-label">
    @(Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address))
</div>
<div data-container-for="address" class="k-edit-field">
    @(Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address, new { style = "width:100%;", @readonly = "readonly", @class = "k-textbox", data_bind = "text: address" }))
</div>

<div class="k-edit-label">
    @(Html.LabelFor(model => model.Start))
</div>
<div data-container-for="start" class="k-edit-field">
    @(Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Start, new { style = "width:100%;", @class = "k-textbox", @readonly = "readonly", data_bind = "value: start" }))
</div>

<div class="k-edit-label">
   @(Html.LabelFor(model => model.End))
</div>
<div data-container-for="end" class="k-edit-field">
    @(Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.End, new { style = "width:100%;", @class = "k-textbox", @readonly = "readonly", data_bind = "value: end" }))
</div>

<div class="k-edit-label">
    @(Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsAllDay))
</div>
<div data-container-for="isAllDay" class="k-edit-field">
    @(Html.DisplayFor(model => model.IsAllDay, new { @class = "k-checkbox", @readonly = "readonly", data_bind = "value: isAllDay" }))
</div>

<div class="k-edit-label">
    @(Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description))
</div>
<div data-container-for="description" class="k-edit-field">
    @(Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "k-textbox", @readonly = "readonly", data_bind = "value: description" }))
</div>

<div class="k-edit-label">
    @(Html.LabelFor(model => model.DutyID))
</div>
<div data-container-for="duties" data-task-id="@Model.TaskID" class="k-edit-field">
      </div>

@{
    ViewContext.FormContext = null;
}
```

and then I add a PanelBar with binding to a hierarchical model... yes it's supposed to be possible:

see [link for hierarchical model binding](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/panelbar/overview):

```
(Html.Kendo().PanelBar()
    .Name("dutyPanel")
    .ExpandMode(PanelBarExpandMode.Single)
    .BindTo(Model.Duties, mappings =>
   {
       mappings.For<PanelGroup>(binding => binding //define first level of panelbar
           .ItemDataBound((item, dutygrp) => //define mapping between panelbar item properties and the model properties
               {
                   item.Text = dutygrp.Text;
                   item.ImageUrl = dutygrp.ImageUrl;
               })
           .Children(dutygrp => dutygrp.Items)); //define which property of the model contains the children
       mappings.For<PanelGroupItem>(binding => binding
           .ItemDataBound((item, duty) =>
               {
                   item.Text = duty.Text;
                   item.ImageUrl = duty.ImageUrl;
               }));
   })
```

But then, when I run the app, and navigate to the page, before the Index action for the controller even fires, I get a:

System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code

HResult=-2147467261

Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source=Kendo.Mvc

The line :

```
.BindTo(Model.Duties, mappings =>
```

Shows that Duties, a model member, is null. Yeah, no kidding it's null... The Action from the controller wasn't even hit yet.

I guess this is a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with javascript binding - and didn't use the MVC version.

My Panel... (tadaaaa)

```
    <div id="dutyPanel"></div>
```

my javascript to load panel when scheduler item edits:

```
$(function () {

////bind to the scheduler edit event
var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
scheduler.bind("edit", onSchedulerEdit);

function onSelect(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
}

function onSchedulerEdit(e) {

    var d = e.event.Duties;
    $("#dutyPanel").kendoPanelBar({
        expandMode: "multiple",
        select: onSelect,
        dataSource: jQuery.makeArray(d)
    });
};


});
```

the data object I use to fill from the DB.... (controller Read function - get all 'duties' for each item in schedule all at once)

```
    public class PanelItem
{
    public string text              { get; set; }
    public string cssClass          { get; set; } // Add custom CSS class to the item, optional
    public string url               { get; set; } // link url for navigation to topic if required, optional
    public string imageUrl          { get; set; } // item image URL, optional
    public string spriteCssClass    { get; set; } // item image sprite CSS class, optional
    public string contentUrl        { get; set; } // content URL to load within an item, optional
    public bool   expanded          { get; set; } // item is rendered expanded, optional
}


public class PanelGroup : PanelItem
{

    public List<PanelItem> items { get; set; } // Sub item collection
}
```

So, see back in javascript? The 'Duties' member in the Event is of type PanelGroup

Oh! You want to indent panel bar items?

In my ScheduleItemTemplate.cshtml - add the styles there:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .panelbarHeader {
        font-size: 1em;
        font-weight: normal;
    }

    .panelbarItem {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: .9em;
        font-weight: normal;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
</style>
```

When filling the PanelGroup object from DB, set the cssClass there:

```
List<DB_Result_Object> results = db.Database.SqlQuery<DB_Result_Object>(commandSQL, strParams.ToArray()).ToList();

    List<TaskViewModel> result = results.ToList().Select(item => new TaskViewModel
            {
                TaskID = item.CalendarAppointmentID,
                Title = item.FieldSuitableForTitleShow),
                Start = item.CalendarAppointmentDateStart,
                End = item.CalendarAppointmentDateEnd,
                StartTimezone = null,
                EndTimezone = null,
                Description = item.CalendarAppointmentDetail.StripMarkup(), // yeah - a string extension method...
                IsAllDay = (item.CalendarAppointmentIsAllDayEvent > 0),
                RecurrenceRule = null,
                RecurrenceException = null,
                RecurrenceID = null,
                OwnerID = item.TheGuysID,
                Duties = GetDuties(item.PrimaryID) // another function to get the duties...

            }).ToList();


            return result.AsQueryable();
```

And in the GetCalendarDuties:

```
List<PanelGroup> panels = new List<PanelGroup>();
```

The usual DB stuff... and then...

spin through the results...and for each new group...however you determine yours...

```
pg = new PanelGroup() { text = ThisGroupName, cssClass = "panelbarHeader", imageUrl = string.Format("Content/scheduler/img/{0}.png", imageNameForGroup), items = new List<PanelItem>() };
panels.Add(pg);
```

and for each new item - however you determine yours...

```
pg.items.Add(new PanelItem { text = ThisItemName, cssClass = "panelbarItem", imageUrl = string.Format("Content/scheduler/img/{0}.png", imageNameForItem) });
```

Voila...panelbar in scheduler item template.